# Communication between node.js and WCF service hosted in a windows service

Tags: node.js, wcf, windows-services

I have a node.js application and a WCF service hosted in a windows service running on the same machine. I need to pass messages from Node.JS app to the WCF service exposed via windows service.It can be uni or bi directional communication. Can you help me to know how to achieve this?

My requirement is to open a communication channel between NodeJS and the WCF service hosted inside Windows Service. My WCF service has net.tcp binding.

Comment: And what does it do on that binding? SOAP? JSON? Something else? Could you change it to a BasicHttpBinding?

Comment: Did you check out [wcf.js](https://github.com/yaronn/wcf.js/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: JSON will be good. I need to pass a string from my NodeJS application to WCF service. Using net.tcp is a requirement as that service talks to another application using that binding. Im trying to define one more endpoint with BasicHttpBinding, and using wcf.js in nodeJs.

Comment: The question isn't very complete - how much of the interface can you control, what are the specs of the parts you can't change?

Comment: Henk, I can make all needed changes in interfaces or in code.

Comment: Both applications' code can be changed as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by modifying my WCF service and adding another end point for webHttpBinding. From Node.Js application I can access this endpoint of my WCF service.